# Python Tkinter: Double Click to Edit Text

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm messing around with a notepad application using Tkinter and I would like to have a label centered above the main text box for a user to label the note. I would like to be able to double-click on the label to edit it. When the user clicks out of the label text area then it would save the text there. I understand I could make a simple text area for the user to type into but I would also like it to be centered and not a blinking cursor the entire time. I'm new to messing with Tkinter so maybe there is a simple solution or better approach. Thank you for any help!

Comment: You could use a normal Entry widget, with its state set to DISABLED so that there's no insertion cursor.  Bind to the `<Double-Button-1>` event to change the state to NORMAL, and to `<FocusOut>` to change back to DISABLED.

Comment: Sounds like a great recommendation! I'll give it a try

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a label that is configured so that when you double-click it you overlay an entry widget.

Something like this, for example:

```
class EditableLabel(tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.bind("<Double-1>", self.edit_start)
        self.entry.bind("<Return>", self.edit_stop)
        self.entry.bind("<FocusOut>", self.edit_stop)
        self.entry.bind("<Escape>", self.edit_cancel)

    def edit_start(self, event=None):
        self.entry.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, relwidth=1.0, relheight=1.0, anchor="center")
        self.entry.focus_set()

    def edit_stop(self, event=None):
        self.configure(text=self.entry.get())
        self.entry.place_forget()

    def edit_cancel(self, event=None):
        self.entry.delete(0, "end")
        self.entry.place_forget()
```

You can then use this like a normal label, like in the following example.

```
root = tk.Tk()
label = EditableLabel(root, text="double-click to edit me")
text = tk.Text(root)
label.pack(side="top", fill="x", padx=2, pady=2)
text.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Works exactly as needed thank you so much!

Comment: Would it be possible to add a callback for `edit_stop()`?

Comment: @ego-layatman-bay: yes, of course. You can bind almost anything to a function.